# Doubt on limit of a sequence of random variables

Tags: calculus, limits, probability-theory, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

Let's define a probability space $(\Omega$, $\mathcal{F}$, $\mathbb{P})$ and a sequence of random variables $(X_n)_{n\geq0}$ defined on it.

---

If I assume that the limit of such a sequence of random variables exists, that is
\begin{equation*}
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n = \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n = \limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n = X
\end{equation*} 
considering that $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\bigg(\inf\limits_{k\geq n}X_n\bigg)$ and $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\bigg(\sup\limits_{k\geq n}X_n\bigg)$, ***could I say that the above equation corresponds to stating that:***
\begin{equation*}
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n = \inf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n = \sup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n = X
\end{equation*} 
***?***

I think that it is not possible, but I am searching for confirmation/rejection of my consideration.

Comment: The statement is not even true for real numbers. Take $x_n=(-1)^n/n$. Just because a limit exists does not mean it has to coincide with the supremum and the infimum

Comment: Ok, as expected. My question raised since I have encountered the following statement: given two sequences of r.v.'s $(Y_n)_{n\geq 0}$ and $(X_n)_{n\geq0}$ and a constant $a$ such that $\mathbb{E}\{Y_n\}\leq\frac{1}{b-a}\mathbb{E}\{(X_n-a)^{+}\}$, then, taking limit on both sides, one gets:
\begin{equation*}
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\{Y_n\} \leq \frac{1}{b-a}\sup\limits_{n}\mathbb{E}\{(X_n-a)^+\}
\end{equation*}

Why does this hold true? @FoobazJohn

Comment: **EDIT**: two constants $a$ and $b$ such that (...)

Comment: $\inf_{n \to \infty}$ and $\sup_{n \to \infty}$ don't really make sense, as notation. You take infima and suprema of sets. So do you mean $\inf_n X_n = \inf \{X_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$?

Comment: Yeah, of course, sorry, my mistake @NathanielMayer